# phonegap uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token < (phonegap + wp json api)

Tags: android, json, api, cordova, jquery-mobile

I tried to put a an Android phonegap app with WP serving content. while phonegap app running JQM framework. I did this a couple of time and it worked fine.

However, in this new app i did, i had this **uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token <**

**My codes to retrieve json**

```
function loadWPCatIndex() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.skywin.my/?json=get_category_index&callback=?", function(data){
        console.log(data);
        plistmenu = $('#product_list');
        $.each(data.categories.reverse(), function(i, item) {
            categoriesID[i] = {wpcatname: item.title, wpcatid: item.id, wpcatparent: item.parent};
        });

        $.each(categoriesID, function(i, item) {
            if (item.wpcatparent == 0) {
                plistmenu.append('<option value ="'+item.wpcatname+'" data-pcatid="'+item.wpcatid+'">'+item.wpcatname+'</option>');
            }        
        });

        $.each(categoriesID, function(i, item) {
            if (item.wpcatparent != 0) {
                $('#product_list option[data-pcatid="'+item.wpcatparent+'"]').after('<option value ="'+item.wpcatname+'" data-pcatid="'+item.wpcatid+'"> - '+item.wpcatname+'</option>');
            }
        });
        plistmenu.children(':first').attr('selected','selected');
        $('#product-page-loader').hide();
        InitMenuEvent();
        $('#product-menu').fadeIn();
    });

}
```

**Json response in browser**

```
?({"status":"ok","count":4,"categories":[{"id":4,"slug":"accessories","title":"Accessories","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1},{"id":8,"slug":"handsfree-kit","title":"Handsfree Kit","description":"","parent":4,"post_count":1},{"id":5,"slug":"nokia","title":"Nokia","description":"","parent":3,"post_count":1},{"id":3,"slug":"phones","title":"Phones","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1}]})
```

All this work fine if i run it as a webapp in the browser. But when i compiled it to android app, i get the error **Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token <**

Full Error Message

Web Console | Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at http://mydomain.my/?json=get_category_index&callback=jQuery18207101479058610589_1357737767961&_=1357737767978:1

*Edit* Added Screenshot link as suggested by *ninetwozero* Thanks :)
[Screen Shot](https://hosted.vinnetwork.com/unexpectedtoken.png)
[image: https://hosted.vinnetwork.com/unexpectedtoken.png]

Would appreciate if anyone could really come into help. Appreciate.

P.s. I run similar code in other domain for other app, it works though.

Comment: You can post a link to a screenshot, and we'll be able to "inline" it for you. :)

Comment: Edited: Added link to screenshot. Thanks @ninetwozero

Comment: Did you whitelist http://www.skywin.my?

Comment: Hi @SimonMacDonald yes i did. All whitelisted

Comment: what does console.log(data) output?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you gotten it to work?

Comment: BTW my answer to you Simon would be that there is no output and in my webserver log no request appears. So Android is blocking the request before it gets sent.